# What are the two tenses used in this passage?

Tags: tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

Which are the two tenses used in this passage?

[image: My friend Rebecca]

> I have known my friend Rebecca for a long time. We first met at a friend's birthday party five years ago. We found out that we both liked techno and Green Day, so I invited Rebecca over to my place. We listened to music together and soon became best friends.
>
> Three years ago, Rebecca's parents invited me to go on holiday with them! It was great. We spent three wonderful weeks in a little cottage in Ireland. Rebecca and I loved walking along the beautiful beach. We took a lot of photos and had a lot of fun.
>
> Two years ago I spent a week in hospital and Rebecca came to see me every day. But then, last year, Rebecca's father changed his job, and they moved to another town. Since then we haven't seen each other very much, but we've talked on the phone and written emails to each other.

Comment: Except for the last sentence, the verbs are all past tense. But the last sentence has all three clauses in the perfect construction, and the perfect auxiliary verbs (_we haven't_ and _I've_) are all  present tense.

Comment: And the starting also, where it says, "I have known Rebecca...."